# PHP - Change value if same and multiple in array exept the first

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to change values of an array if one af the value is several times into and change duplicate values exept the first.

I have this array:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 0
      'data-time-end' => int 5
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'data-time-start' => int 6
      'data-time-end' => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 11
      'data-time-end' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 16
      'data-time-end' => int 20
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'data-time-start' => int 21
      'data-time-end' => int 25
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 30
      'data-time-end' => int 35
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 40
      'data-time-end' => int 45
```

In this example I have two times `'id' = int 1` and three times `'id' = int 3` .
What I would like to do is to keep the first ID but set other duplicate IDs to `NULL` and return an array like this:

```
 array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'data-time-start' => int 0
      'data-time-end' => int 5
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'data-time-start' => int 6
      'data-time-end' => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 11
      'data-time-end' => int 15
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'data-time-start' => int 16
      'data-time-end' => int 20
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'data-time-start' => int 21
      'data-time-end' => int 25
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 30
      'data-time-end' => int 35
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => null
      'data-time-start' => int 40
      'data-time-end' => int 45
```

I'm not an expert in php ...

**EDIT 1 :**

Tried with that:

```
function setNulForDuplicatesInArray($arr, $keyToFind)
    {
        $newArr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
            if (in_array($arr[$i], $newArr))
                $newArr[$i][$keyToFind] = null;
            else
                $newArr[] = $arr[$i];
        }
        return $newArr;
    }

var_dump(setNulForDuplicatesInArray($arr, 'id'))
```

But nothing happened

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why not through `var_dump()`?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Pretty bad advice, you'd be amazed how many problems here would have been obvious right away if a `var_dump` had been used instead of a `print_r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little function that should do the trick:

```
function replace($arr) {
    $newArr = array();
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++) {
        if(in_array($arr[$i], $newArr))
            $newArr[$i]['id'] = 'null';
        else
            $newArr[] = $arr[$i];
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

It loops through the array and checks whether the same entry already exists in `$newArr`. If it does, `id` is set to `null`. If not, the entry is being pushed into `$newArr`.

Please note that in this example `null` is a string. I did that because in your desired result, `null` is a string. If that's not desired, simply remove the surrounding quotes.

Comment: Works nice ! but How to do if my array have other index  like : `array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => int 3` ? I update my post

Comment: I updated my post because array change a litlle... his got some index more

Answer (score 2):

```
function setNulForDuplicates($theArray) {
    $myarray = array();
    for ($ind = 0; $ind < count($theArray); $ind++) {
        if (in_array($theArray[$ind], $myarray)) {
            $myarray[$ind]['id'] = 'null';
        } else {
            $myarray[$ind] = $theArray[$ind];
        }
    }
    return $myarray;
}

var_dump(setNulForDuplicates($arr));
```

Comment: Works nice ! but How to do if my array have other index ? see my post, I updated it ! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=array(
    array("id"=>1),
    array("id"=>2),
    array("id"=>1),
    array("id"=>3),
    array("id"=>4),
    array("id"=>3),
    array("id"=>3)
    );
var_dump($arr);
$tmp=array();
foreach($arr as $k =>$v){
    if(!in_array($v['id'], $tmp)){
        $tmp[]=$v['id'];
    }else{
        $arr[$k]['id']=null;
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Works nice ! but How to do if my array have other index ? see my post, I updated it ! thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use print_r

Comment: Do not understand it for your post.   For example